# How can I resolve a critical section runtime error with PHP sessions in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, runtime-error, critical-section

A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.please help how to resolve this problem I m getting this notification in my WordPress dashboard.

Comment: Is that all it says, or does it refer a file and line number? If not, then I suppose you will have to go figure out where any HTP requests or Rest API calls are getting made, and see to it that you close the session before that. (If possible; if you still needed _write_ access to the session after those calls, then it will probably need more of a rewrite.)

Comment: You may have a look at this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use php sessions in the WordPress environment. They are incompatible, as WordPress manages its own session data.